# Cant Grab data in API due to array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, api

So it is pretty simple but I am having some difficulty.

I am grabbing data from an API and echoing it to the page using PHP and it is working.

However, not when the API data is wrapped in an 'array' or '[]'.

**API 1: (WORKING)**

```
{
"data": 18, 
"data2": 20,  
}
```

**API 2: (NOT WORKING)**

```
[
{
"data": 18, 
"data2": 20,  
}
]
```

**My PHP code:**

```
<?php
$url = "my correct url is here";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$dataprint = $json["data"];
echo $dataprint;
?>
```

Why is the simple change of '[]' messing the code up and not allowing me to print the information?

Comment: Add a condition to check if it's array first before setting `$dataprint` variable. If it is, then use `$dataprint = $json[0]["data"];`

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets are JSON notation for an array 'without' keys (In the decoded php array keys are numeric start with 0, and don't skip any numbers). You can access the data if you adjust one line in your code (add `[0]`):

```
$dataprint = $json[0]["data"];
```